# Auto focus a row in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax

I am totally new to `angular js` . I have a a table which is like -

```
HTML

<table class="table table-striped" id="manageResumeTable">
                                        <thead class="text-center text-info text-capitalize">
                                            <th class="text-center col-xs-1">Sr.No.</th>
                                            <th class="text-center col-xs-4">Document</th>
                                            <th class="text-center col-xs-1">Score</th>
                                            <th class="text-center col-xs-1">QuickScore</th>
                                            <th class="text-center col-xs-5">Actions</th>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tr ng-repeat="file in processResumeFiles" ng-class="{'highlighter-row-Class' : file.id == 1}">
                                            <td class="text-center col-xs-1">{{ file.temporaryId }}</td>
                                            <td class="view-orphan uploadResumeTableCellOverFlow col-xs-4">
                                                {{ file.attributes.name }}
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="text-center col-xs-1">{{file.totalScore}}</td>
                                            <td class="text-center col-xs-1" ng-class= "{'highlighter-QuickScore' : file.attributes.areQuickScoreFieldsMissing}">{{file.attributes.quickScore}}</td>
                                            <td class="text-center col-xs-5">
                                                <button class="btn btn-labeled  btn-info" title="Annotate Un-annotated Words" data-ng-click="getOrphans($index)">
                                                        <i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                                    </button>
                                                <button class="btn btn-labeled  btn-info" ng-show="file.attributes.isUploadedDocument" title="Promote to Gold Standard" data-ng-click="markAsGoldStd(file.attributes.name)">
                                                        <i class="fa fa-share" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                                    </button>
                                                <button class="btn btn-labeled  btn-info" title="Delete from Corpus" data-ng-click="deleteResume(file.attributes.name)">
                                                        <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                                    </button>
                                                <button class="btn btn-labeled  btn-info" title="Add to Tracker" ng-disabled="!file.attributes.isModelHtmlPresent || !isjdDeleted || !jdSelected"
                                                        data-ng-click="moveToJobDescription(file.attributes.name)">
                                                        <i class="fa fa-check-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                                    </button>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
```

Here, I am using a `ng-repeat`. So, data is coming from the ajax call.

Now Here, `file.id == 1` is coming from the ajax call, this is working fine , I also have a `scrollbar` for this Now I want to focus that row only if the `file.id == 1` . Now I am able to highlight that but not able to focus that. So can  any one please help me ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use ng-if . Source: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf

Comment: What do you understand by "focus". You want that the browser auto scroll to the first line ?

Comment: Yes scroll bar should be at that row

Comment: You don't have an input element in here. Focus only works on input elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
$timeout(function(){
angular.element('.highlighter-row-Class').focus();
},100);
```

This will focus on the first row which has the 'highlighter-row-Class' it will look for it every 100ms. If you want this to happen when the data is loaded just add this code the to the ajax response handler.

Answer (score 0):

"Focus" is not the term you're looking for here.

Focus is when you want to type into a field and the focus is on that field(e.g. when you switch fields using the `Tab` key).

You don't seem to have any input fields at all in this table.

What you're instead looking for I think is **scrolling** to a particular row.

This is fairly easy if you already have `ng-repeat` and a unique id coming via AJAX; all you've got to really do is something like this on your row:

```
<td id = "file{{file.id}}">Some text here</td>
```

Then just use a hyperlink or `window.location.assign()` JavaScript call to scroll there:

```
<a href="#file1">Scroll to row 1</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

This directive will make the input element to focus when the condition is true.

```
<input type="text" focus-on="file.id">
```

directive:

```
.directive('focusOn', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      focusOn: '='
    },
  link: function($scope, $element) {

  $scope.$watch('focusOn', function(shouldFocus) {
    if (shouldFocus) {
      $element[0].focus();
    }
  });

}
  };

})
```

Comment: Where's `focusWhen`?

Comment: sorry thats a typo. Now Updated